# Get last value from an array using Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, google-apps-script, google-apps

I need to get last value from an array and I keep getting this error when I use slice

> TypeError: Cannot find function slice in object Sun Jul 23 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST). (line 15, file

If I use length -1 I get NaN.

This is the code I am using it.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  var today = new Date(Date.now());
   today.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    Logger.log(today);

var setTotal;
var getToday = values[4].map(Number).indexOf(+today);
Logger.log(getToday);
for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
 var getTotal = values[i][getToday];
       Logger.log(getTotal.slice(-1)[0]); 
 }
}
```

... and this is the table

[full table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLcbc.png)

So I need when it match the current day (today) to retrieve last value from that array (column) which is the Total for that day.

Thank you!

Kind regards,

Comment: What does getTotal look like? If it isn't a string or an array, you cannot slice it: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues() _The values may be of type Number, Boolean, Date, or String,_

Comment: When I debug it says it's a String ....

Comment: Every time? `if (typeof values[i][getToday] == "String") Logger.log("ok to slice");Logger.log(getTotal.slice(-1)[0]); } else console.log("Not ok")`

Comment: It seems like this happens in the header row (5, index 4?). What are you trying to slice out?

Comment: getDataRange will return A1:S61 and getValues will return 2 empty arrays, one Array with Week number from my table and another array with Week Days .... so the Array I need to look and match the date is [4]. Once match the date I need to get last value from that column.

Comment: I don't follow. `getValues()` of A1:S61 should return an array of 61 arrays of 19 elements

Comment: That's correct! I have uploaded the full table .... so you can make an idea.

Comment: So basically you want todays total?

Comment: Exactly! I have another table and will be updated everyday. At the and of the day I just want to get totals for that day and send it to my email :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getTotal is always already a singular value.
Also the way you find your column is brittle due to timezones because you normalize only one date.
If you do it with both dates (which needs to be handled safely unless you want to do index constraints) your column finding approach works.

```
function getTodaysTotal() {
  function toUtcMidnight(date) {
    try {return date.setHours(0,0,0,0);}
    catch(e) {return;}
  }

  var values = SpreadsheetApp
      .getActiveSpreadsheet()
      .getSheetByName("Data")
      .getDataRange()
      .getValues();

  var today = toUtcMidnight(new Date());
  var todaysColumn = values[4].map(toUtcMidnight).map(Number).indexOf(+today);
  var output = values[values.length - 1][todaysColumn];
  return values[values.length - 1][todaysColumn];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method `.pop()` that returns and **removes** the last element from an array.

Make a copy of the original array first and use `.pop()` method and assign it to a new value.

```
var myArray = myArrayCopy
var lastArrayObject = myArrayCopy.pop()
```

Comment: Are there any docs for the language?